# loop to find distance between a point and complex number

Tags: python, image-processing

i need to find distance between array of complex numbers and a point, array is represented by 'r' and 'x' and 'y' represents single point. output so required is loop i applied is like below.

```
for i in range(len(r)):
    dist = [(x-r[i].real) + (y-r[i].imag)j]
```

but it is giving error :

```
File "<ipython-input-70-177fc8f17e19>", line 2
    dist = [(x-r[i].real) + (y-r[i].imag)j]
                                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

how can i get array of complex nummber after subtraction of each complex nummber with (x,y).

Comment: I think the error is coming from the `j` at the end of the line, I don't think it belongs there.

Comment: Also try changing `dist =` to `dist +=`

Comment: i want output as array of complex numbers itself...then how should i proceed..

Comment: seriously, don't just dump your error messages on StackOverflow. Read and analyse the errors you get. We can't learn to write correct python for you. Invest a little more of your **own** time in solving your problems now, and you'll be able to solve far more complicated problems later on.

Answer (score 1):

You had an extra letter in your code by accident it would seem, remove `j` and then you'll need to create the list `dist` before the loop. Inside the loop change `dist =` to `dist +=` so that it appends each and every iteration instead of replacing them.

```
dist = []
for i in range(len(r)): dist += [(x-r[i].real) + (y-r[i].imag)]
```

Note: if you want just the *distance* then use `abs` like `abs((x-r[i].real) + (y-r[i].imag))`

Comment: what should i do if i want result in complex form itself.....i want that answer should include 'j' term also

Comment: There is no j term, you never made one

Comment: If there was one then you'd want to include the 'j' term by doing `,j]`

Comment: `dist += [(x-r[i].real) + (y-r[i].imag),j]`

Comment: Because j doesn't exist